# Same DOM elements on different HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, dom, code-separation

i think my question is a little bit stupid, but I have a problem. There`s a few html pages, for ex.: index.html and rooms.html etc... And a main.js file with scripts for all .html pages. The problem is that i have a variables, like

```
const HTMLelement = document.querySelector('.className');
```

and some functions to work with this HTMLelement. But, this element is only on index.html page, and when im on rooms.html page, i have an error, cause HTMLelement  is not defined and other script does not exists (its important, cause some html build by script.) Also, in main.js I have scripts for all pages, so I cant create new .js file...
So, what is the best way to `separate` scripts for different html pages?

Comment: Why not just check if that element actually exists, before trying to perform any further operations on it ...?

Comment: so, I just need to check 
    if(HTMLelement) {
        //some code
    }
is this ok?

Comment: "Also, in main.js I have scripts for all pages, so I cant create new .js file..." without further information, that argument doesn't hold

Comment: Why does `main.js` contain `all` of the `javascript` from all the pages? Simply chop it up into more files. Make `one file` that has functions for `repeatable content` and include it in `all the HTML` files that need it. Then make `other files` with `page specific functions` where needed and add them only to the `HTML pages for which they were written`.

Comment: Split your JS into parts. One script for the functions that you want to share on all pages and one script for each page that takes care of the page-specific things.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have several ways to solve the issue

**Create specific separate script for each page**

- rooms.html -> rooms.js
- index.html -> index.js

**Checking the existence of nodes before you do something**

```
if(document.querySelectorAll('.className').length == 0){
     // do things
}
```

**Checking the current page before you do something**

```
if(window.location.pathname.indexOf('rooms.html') != -1){
     // do things
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Always validate that an element exists before you try to use it.

```js
const oneEl = document.querySelector('.one');
if (oneEl) {
  oneEl.setAttribute('title', 'This is one');
}

// Below I am trying to get an element by the wrong class name.
const twoEl = document.querySelector('.two');
if (twoEl) {
  // This code will not run
  twoEl.setAttribute('title', 'This is two');
}
```

```html
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="too">Two</div>
```